# how to? ajax synchronize multiple browsers

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

What is the best way to synchronize multiple browsers? For example on the Control Website I would define 5 minutes “red.html” -> 5 minutes “green.html” -> 5  minutes “blue.html” -> loop (back to "red.thml")

**Question:** How can I ensure that the content for all viewers will change simultaneously?

**Technical:** Local Network, Server-Side could be python or php; Every viewer on the same system time

My **first Idea** was: The Backend of the Control Website saves ever 10 seconds an json object with the current URL. The Viewer Website checks every 5 seconds the json object. The 5seconds should be synchronize with clock 12:01:05 -> 12:01:10 -> 12:01:15 ...

Thank You,
Oli

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into [AJAX Push Engine](http://www.ape-project.org/).  I personally don't have any experience with it, but it might be able to handle what you're trying to do.

Comment: Thanky you very much. I like this site.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use long-polling ajax method to achieve this. there are no classic methods how to ensure that all users are being redirected in same time